# how to compute horizontal angle of a pixel from a computer vision camera

Tags: computational-geometry, trigonometry

My program needs to compute the angle of a pixel from a computer vision camera that has 120 degrees horizontal field of view, and resolution of 640 pixels wide and 480 pixels high.

Program receives an X,Y array of pixels for each image frame from camera. For left-most pixel, X would be 0 and angle would be -60 degrees. For right-most pixel, X would be 639 and angle 60 degrees. For center pixel, X would be 320 and angle 0.

How is angle computed when (X is > 0 and < 320) and (>320 and <640)?

Comment: Is this related with the software product **Mathematica(TM)**? This site is about it!

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499409/opencv-calculate-angle-between-camera-and-pixel

Comment: If the lens has a stated angle-of-view of 120 degrees, that generally refers the angle-of-view across a diagonal of the image frame and not the horizontal angle-of-view. The horizontal angle-of-view will be 80% of that (96 degrees). Similarly, the vertical angle-of-view will be 60% of that (72 degrees).

Comment: 120 degrees horizontal field of view

Comment: With a field of view that wide there's bound to be noticeable distortion.  I would use [opencv's camera calibration utility](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html) to get the distortion parameters along with the projection matrix.